# Converting BloombergLP::blpapi::Name to const char *

Tags: c++, casting, bloomberg

I'm starting a project in C++ that involves the Bloomberg API. I've been able to get sample code to compile and link and the output is good, but certain small changes have proven confounding.

For example, when trying to access the name of an Element, I use

```
const char* holderString;
const Element fields = security.getElement(FIELD_DATA);
Element field = fields.getElement(1);
holderString = field.name();
```

and the final line triggers the compile-time error

```
 "no suitable conversion function from "BloombergLP::blpapi::Name"
  to "const char *" exists"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A suggestion: read the documentation. A `Name` is not a `char*`. That's obvious. If there exist a method to *extract* a `char*` from a `Name`, it's probably there. If you can't find a solution, press the F1 key twice and ask support.

Comment: @Amit The high level documentation is fine, but at the level of this detail it seems to be machine-generated from the header files and is not helpful to me.

Comment: It's been a few years since I last saw the API or the documentation, but that doesn't sound quite right. Still, contact support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field.name()` returns a `BloombergLP::blpapi::Name` not a `char *`...

However `Name` has a [`string` method which returns a `const char *`](http://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/cpp/3.9/classblpapi_1_1Name.html#a262bc10ceb2e02b024dd0e527a85c4c7).

Comment: Yeah, `Name name1 = item.name();` works, and the `Name` can then be converted to a string with `name1.string()`.